# Where query with NULL parameter

Tags: sql-server

Why this is not possible in SQL Server?

I am getting:

> Incorrect syntax near '@pp'.

SQL:

```
declare @pp INT = null

select * 
from ExtraExaminationsReportView  
where [PayerId] is @pp
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize keywords, you can try to make your query dynamic instead

Comment: why do you want to do it this way? you cannot change the `@pp` to e.g. 4. Your query would be `where  [PayerId] is 4` which is definitly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you wrote won't work for a few reasons.

Firstly, if `@pp` was an `int`, the `IS @PP` syntax is incorrect, `IS` syntax is used in conjunction with `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL IS NULL
```

You can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL IS 1
```

You'd need to use `=` when checking for a numeric value:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL = 1
```

So to cater for both a `NULL` value or an `INT` value, you can use an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause to check the value like so:

```
DECLARE @pp INT = NULL  -- you can set this to 1 to show it works for both

-- temp table with a null value and an int value = 1
SELECT  1 val
INTO    #TMP
UNION ALL
SELECT  NULL

SELECT  *
FROM    #TMP
WHERE   ( @pp IS NULL
          AND val IS NULL
        )  
        OR ( @pp IS NOT NULL
             AND val = @pp
           )  

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Modifying your code:

```
DECLARE @pp INT = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM ExtraExaminationsReportView  
WHERE   ( @pp IS NULL
          AND PayerId IS NULL
        )
        OR ( @pp IS NOT NULL
             AND PayerId = @pp
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your query logic. The only way is:

```
declare @pp INT = null
select * from ExtraExaminationsReportView  where  ([PayerId] IS NULL OR [PayerId] = @pp)
```

Comment: the issue with your query is that if `@pp` is a number, then you will also return rows where `playerId` is `null`, which may not be desired.